# How to plot a multicolored curve using a single plot command in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I understand correctly, the function:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, y)
```

plots len(x)-1 separate line segments - one going from (x[0], y[0]) to (x[1],y[1]), one going from (x[1],y[1]) to (x[2], y[2]), etc. In my application, I want to display a curve consisting of a series of line segments connecting data points in this way, but there is an extra piece of data (z) associated with the transition between each of these data points, that I want to represent by the color of the line segment. Clearly one way of doing this is the following:

```
for i in range(len(x)-1)):
    matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x[i:i+2],y[i:i+2], color=z[i])
```

but is there a way to do it that doesn't involve a separate call to matplotlib.pyplot.plot for each line segment?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [`matplotlib.collections.LineCollection`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection) which accepts a `colors` parameter (sequence of RGBA tuples).