# Python matplotlib : plot3D with a color for 4D

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping, mplot3d

I am trying to make a 3D plot from x, y, z points list, and I want to plot color depending on the values of a fourth variable rho.

Currently I have ;

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot3D(cell_x, cell_y, cell_z, linestyle='None', marker='o', markersize = 5, antialiased=True)
ax.set_xlim3d(0.45, 0.55)
ax.set_ylim3d(0.45, 0.55)
ax.set_zlim3d(0.45, 0.55)
```

How to add cell_rho (my fourth array) as the color of my x, y, z points ? (for example for a jet colormap).

Thank you very much.

EDIT : I can't use scatter plots because for my 18000 points scatter plots are very slow compared to plot3d with markers only.

Comment: Something along these lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134879/how-to-plot-a-multicolored-curve-using-a-single-plot-command-in-matplotlib ?

Comment: Even with that, I don't understand how to convert rho to values that can be passed to the "color" option of my plot 3D...

Comment: Are you trying to mashup a multicolored line (http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/MulticoloredLine) and  3d line (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#line-plots)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to display a simple 3D scatterplot, can't you just use `scatter`?
E.g.,

```
x, y, z = randn(100), randn(100), randn(100)
fig = plt.figure()
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=randn(100))
plt.show()
```

(I'm running the above code under `python -pylab`.)

[image]

It seems, on the contrary, that with `plot3D` you must convert your fourth dimension to RGB tuples.

Comment: My problem is that for my 18000 points scatter plots are way slower than plot3D with markers only...